# What is the relation between metric thread nut hexagon diameter and the major diameter

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, cad, technical-drawing

If we a M12 bolt what will the relation between the major diameter and the hexagon diameter be?
If we calculate it geometrically it should be $E(Hexagon\space diameter)=\sqrt{3}d(major \space diameter)$ is this correct or other factors are taken in?

Comment: If you test your expression  against the dimensions of an M4 nut, what is the result? Correct? And M8?

Answer (score 1):

A quick check gives the following:

| Size | Thread *d* | √3*d* | Nut | Error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| M5 | 5 | 8.66 | 8 | 8.25% |
| M6 | 6 | 10.39 | 10 | 3.9% |
| M8 | 8 | 13.86 | 13 | 6.62% |
| M10 | 10 | 17.32 | 17 | 1.88% |
| M12 | 12 | 20.78 | 19 | 9.37% |
| M16 | 16 | 27.71 | 24 | 15.46% |
| M20 | 20 | 34.64 | 30 | 15.47% |
| M24 | 24 | 41.57 | 36 | 15.47% |
| M30 | 30 | 51.96 | 46 | 12.96% |